# Coordinate transform of Kerr metric to Kerr-Schild coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

the transformation from [Boyer-Lindquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)  $\{t,r,\theta,\phi\}$ coordinates to Kerr-Schild $\{t',r,\theta,\phi' \}$coordinates can be written as
$$
dt' = dt + \frac{2 M r}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2} dr, \;\;\; d\phi'=d\phi + \frac{a}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2} dr. \tag{1}
$$
or more explicitly by
$$
t' = t + 2 M \int \frac{r dr}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2}, \;\;\; \phi' = \phi + a \int \frac{dr}{r^2 - 2 M r + a^2}. \tag{2}
$$
Now I understand that these are equivalent. Since the simply differentiating (2) leads to (1).

The expressions (2) leave room for constants. I was wondering how we set these these constants.
Do we perhaps want that $t'$ and $t$ are equal at some special point $r = C$, where $C = \text{const.}$? The same for $\phi'$ and $\phi$. But what choice of $C$ is a "reasonable one".

Edit:
We probably want $t'$ and $\phi'$ to be real, that fixed the imaginary parts of $C$. But not the real ones.

Comment: Those constants are just the initial t and φ, you can set them to 0 since the metric is independend of those 2 coordinates. Since the [transformation](http://relativity.yukterez.net/89.html) is done via the differentials the constants won't even show up though.

Comment: . . . leads to (1).  I couldn't edit it as it is two single characters.

Comment: @Yukterez I understand that. But I was unsure about the domain of the new coordinates, which seems important if you want to calculate quantities like the area of the Black-Hole in the Kerr-Schild coordinates.